# WPF custom drawing mysterious drawing error

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have a control that draws directly to a custom canvas.  The custom control calculates how big to draw a circle based on physical dimensions.  The behavior I'm seeing is identical whether I use the Ellipse XAML element or custom draw the control.

Basically, once the size of the element gets big enough to be larger than the smallest dimension of the canvas, it's drawn location gets offset from the clipping rectangle.  The end result is the center point (drawn by a different control) is correct but the circle is shifted--and the edges are clipped.

Example:

[image: Rendering Example]

As long as my calculated center and the actual center line up, the control is rendered properly.  I can't find anywhere that I'm explicitly setting the clipping.

My question is 2 fold:

- What's going on?
- How can I accurately render to the center of the arranged area?  I'm using the following to calculate the center point:

  ```
  Point center = new Point( RenderSize.Width / 2, RenderSize.Height / 2);
  ```

That works the majority of the time, but not when the circle gets beyond a certain size.

Circle Control Code:

```
public class CirclePoint : UIElement
{
    // field
    double radius;

    // additional properties
    MetersPerPixel -- set by container, attached property, affects measure
    RadiusInMeters -- set by application, affects measure
    FillColor -- set by application, affects render
    ObjectColor -- set by applicaiton, affects render
    StrokeThickness -- set by application, affects measure, render
    Location -- center point, set by application, affects layout

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

        radius = RadiusInMeters / MetersPerPixel;

        double halfPenWidth = StrokThickness / 2;
        double diameter = 2 * (radius + halfPenWidth);

        return new Size(diameter, diameter);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        SolidColorBrush fillBrush = // from FillColor, frozen
        SolidColorBrush edgeBrush = // from ObjectColor, frozen
        Pen edgePen = // from edgeBrush, StrokeThickness, frozen

        double halfPenWidth = StrokeThickness / 2;

        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(fillBrush, edgePen,
            new Point(RenderSize.Width / 2, RenderSize.Height / 2),
            radius - halfPenWidth, radius - halfPenWidth);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the abbreviated notation, but I'm trying to summarize the boiler plate code with pertinent information.

The custom panel is a lot more complicated since it is responsible for deconflicting labels and such, but the pertinent information is here:

```
public class PhysicalPane : Pane
{
    // Pertinent Properties

    PhysicalArea // affects layout

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size screen = new Screen(ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
        double metersPerDisplayUnit = // calculation based on screen and other context

        Size newDesiredSize = // from constraint, adjusting for double.Infinity

        foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(constraint);
            SetMetersPerPixel(child, metersPerDisplayUnit);

            newDesiredSize.Width = Math.Max(newDesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            newDesiredSize.Height = Math.Max(newDesiredSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }

        return newDesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            Location childLocation = GetLocation(child);
            // LocationToPoint is very well tested.
            Point displayPoint = LocationToPoint(childLocation, PhysicalArea, finalSize);

            displayPoint.X -= child.DesiredSize.Width / 2;
            displayPoint.Y -= child.DesiredSize.Height / 2;

            Rect locationRect = new Rect(displayPoint, child.DesiredSize);

            child.Arrange(locationRect);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

---

It turns out that the placement of the circle was wrong because the DesiredSize and RenderSize are different.  To fix the placement in my `CirclePoint` I had to change the center point logic like this:

```
double xOffset = (DesiredSize.Width - RenderSize.Width) / 2;
double yOffset = (DesiredSize.Width - RenderSize.Width) / 2;

Point center = new Point(xOffset + radius, yOffset + radius);
```

There remains one problem with this solution:

- My circle is still clipped visibly.

Comment: Hard to tell without having seen the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Note: ClipToBounds has no effect.  @Clemens, will attempt to get minimal code in place....

Comment: @Clemens, pertinent parts of extra code is added.

Comment: Looks all ok so far. I've dumped this into a test project and stripped off all the abbreviated stuff (and replaced MeasureOverride by MeasureCore in CirclePoint) and it renders as expected. What do you exactly mean with "when the circle gets beyond a certain size"? Which size is that?

Comment: Take the smallest dimension of the container's dimension, and when the diameter is larger than that I get the misplacement.  It doesn't matter what size the container is, that's the relationship that causes the problem.  The larger the diameter, the worse the problem.

Comment: How do you override MeasureCore in WPF?  It's a sealed method.

Comment: Not in UIElement, which seems to be the base class of CirclePoint.

Comment: You wrote that "LocationToPoint is very well tested", so it gives you the desired Point, but then the CirclePoint is arranged elsewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93824/discussion-between-berin-loritsch-and-clemens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer to my positioning problem was that there was a difference between DesiredSize and RenderSize once the child was bigger in any dimension than the parent container.  I had to adjust my `OnRender` method like this:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    SolidColorBrush fillBrush = // from FillColor, frozen
    SolidColorBrush edgeBrush = // from ObjectColor, frozen
    Pen edgePen = // from edgeBrush, StrokeThickness, frozen

    double halfPenWidth = StrokeThickness / 2;
    double xOffset = (DesiredSize.Width - RenderSize.Width) / 2;
    double yOffset = (DesiredSize.Width - RenderSize.Width) / 2;

    Point center = new Point(xOffset + radius, yOffset + radius);

    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(fillBrush, edgePen, center,
        radius - halfPenWidth, radius - halfPenWidth);
}
```

That allowed the circle to be drawn in the correct location no matter how big the circle was in relation to the parent.

My clipping problem was due to the layout pane having `ClipToBounds=True`.  That is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the center of a UIElement:

```
Point topLeftCorner = yourEllipse.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));//Get the point of the topleft corner of your UIElement
Point center = new Point(topLeftCorner.X + yourEllipse.Width / 2, topLeftCorner.Y + yourEllipse.Height / 2);//The center of your ellipse
```

Comment: That might work from the container, but from inside the ellipse itself it offsets everything outside of where it needs to be.  Trying this put the circle to the bottom right of the desired location.